# Excel copy paste value different worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

In sheet1 I want to copy the values of the columns a,c,d,g and paste that to the bottom of sheet2 in columns a,b,c,d

I've been having difficultly with this because the columns of a,c,d,g contain formulas so when I use copy/destination method it ends up breaking the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 3 methods, and all essentially use copy/paste

1. Use the method that [rwtwm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18106547/1370425) suggested. Example code would be

   ```
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Copy
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
       Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   ```
2. copy the values

   ```
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Value = _
       Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Value
   ```
3. Copy the data into an array, and then use that to copy that array into the other sheet

   ```
   Dim MyData
   MyData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10") = MyData
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this Sean, but the range of cells in sheet1 will vary, and I would like to put range from sheet1 at the bottom of first open cell in sheet2, so I wouldn't be pasting over the same information everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use copy and pastespecial because then you'll have the choice of just pasting the values or formatting as well. But if you don't like that route you can also assign the values in a column to an array and paste it in.

Here's an example of how you would go about such problem:

```
Sub test()
Dim colA As Variant
Dim colB As Variant
Dim colC As Variant
Dim lrow As Long

'putting the ranges into arrays
With Sheets(1).UsedRange
    colA = .Columns("A")
    colB = .Columns("B")
    colC = .Columns("C")
End With

'putting arrays back into ranges
'note the use of resize to fit the target range with arrays
With Sheets(2)
    lrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    .Range("A" & lrow).Resize(UBound(colA, 1), 1) = colA
    .Range("B" & lrow).Resize(UBound(colB, 1), 1) = colB
    .Range("C" & lrow).Resize(UBound(colC, 1), 1) = colC
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the paste special method on the range in question. See the link at [the Microsoft help resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx).
You will require the modifier xlPasteValues.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using copy and paste to minimize potential errors, also this is a just for a small section of a macro that I'm writing so I'm trying to use faster methods like value. Thanks though!